# how to get element with xpath by attribute value

Tags: xpath, scrapy

trying to get the next page arrow link from [this page](https://www.mammut.com/eu/en/featured/5810/page/page/3). however
`response.selector.xpath('//a[aria-label="Next page"]')` yields []. help! :)
I was able to solve it with `response.selector.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "Pagination_arrowItem")]/a')[1].attrib['href']` but then run into an issue if it's the firts page and only one arrow is shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get it with:

```
response.selector.xpath('//a[@data-e2e-test="pagination-next"]')
```

See [Scrapy documentation](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/) for more.

Comment: Correct, although that the name of the attribute ending with `-test`, could mean that it will not last...

Comment: Same can be said about any other attribute or structure in page, @SiebeJongebloed. Right now it works, and if it will change, then the code can be updated to reference the updated structure. That's the nature of the game.

Comment: Also true. I will add an alternative answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since the anker itself is using a workable @data-e2e-test attribute, its name seems a bit temporary. Therefore you also could use:

```
//*[starts-with(@class,"Pagination_container")]/div[position()=last()]/a
```

Comment: Amazing. thanks. just for interest sake, can you achieve the same with the css selector?

Comment: [Many roads lead to Rome;](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Milliarium_Aureum)